# finding the whole number portion of a number

Tags: javascript

How can you find the whole number of a given decimal or other number in JavaScript?

```
Given  Result
-----  ------
1.2    1

1.5    1

1.9    1
```

What's the best way to perform this for both positive and negative numbers?

Answer (score 51):

Using [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```
Math.floor(number)
```

Comment: number>0?Math.floor(number):Math.ceil(number) to handle the negative case if needed

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `newNumber = parseInt(number, 10);`

Comment: You shuld always stipulate the base parameter with parseint e.g. parseInt(number,10). The if you do not, zero-padded numbers may parse as octal.

Comment: You're right, i have forgot this.

In the most cases this conversion will done

Comment: This is the best answer if you do not want any rounding, just getting the integer part.

Answer (score 10):

With ES6, there is [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc), this function returns the integer part of a number by removing any fractional digits.

This differs from the `Math.floor()` while handling the negative numbers.

```js
console.log(Math.trunc(3.14)); // 3

console.log(Math.trunc(-3.14)); // -3
console.log(Math.floor(-3.14)); // Here floor gives -4.
```

So essentially you can get rid of writing this longer expression

```
number > 0 ? Math.floor(number) : Math.ceil(number)
```

Answer (score 8):

Bitwise operators - the shortest syntax for positive numbers having integral part of number <= 2^31-1

```
~~1.2 // 1
~~1.5 // 1
~~1.9 // 1

1.2>>0 // 1
1.5>>0 // 1
1.9>>0 // 1

1.2|0 // 1
1.5|0 // 1
1.9|0 // 1
```

With values exceeding 2^31-1 will return incorrect results.

Comment: This is the best answer for me, although it's less readable from `Math.trunc()`. Hovewer it has small additional adventage: using `~~-0.1` we get `0` while using `Math.trunc(-0.1)` we get `-0`

Answer (score 6):

for negative numbers you can just use Math.abs(num) and it will knock off the - sign from the start